# In javascript can we invoke a function as functionName(5)(3);?

Tags: javascript

In javascript can we invoke a function as mentioned below? if so what is the logic behind it?

```
var pro = function(a){
...
}

pro(5)(3);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
var pro = function(a) { return function(b) { return a * b; } };
console.log(pro(5)(3));  // 15
```

Basically, if the return value of a function is itself a function, you can then turn around and call the returned function immediately in the same expression;  that's what that syntax means.  You could also use an intermediate variable:

```
var times5 = pro(5);
console.log(times5(3)); // 15
```

In the above case, the result is the same as if you had defined `times5` directly like this:

```
function times5(b) { return 5 * b; }
```

There are plenty of applications for functions returning functions; in general, using functions as regular values in expressions that get passed around to other functions and so on is called [Higher-order programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_programming). As a practical matter in Javascript, you often have to do this when dynamically creating or associating web page elements with action functions; calling function-returning functions allows you make sure that each function gets its own unique variables, avoiding the reuse that otherwise happens due to the limitations of `var` scoping.

In some other languages, when you pass too few parameters to a function, it will automatically return another function that will finish the job when passed the rest of the arguments.  This is called [*currying*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) after [Haskell Curry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_Curry), and in [the language given his other name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haskell_(programming_language)), that's actually the only way to write a function of multiple parameters: write a function that returns a function that returns a function... that takes the last parameter and returns the result.

Answer (score 2):

If `pro(5)` returns a function, then yes.

If not, then you'll get an error.